# promise + redux + redux-thunk: typescript error "is not assignable to type 'Promise<any>"

Tags: typescript, promise, redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to understand how declaring types for promises work.

I got a redux webapp with `react-thunk` for async actions. The flow is:

1. React component calls redux action (`workbench-group.view.tsx`) and sets is own loading state
2. redux actions calls api service (`workbench-group.actions.ts`)
3. api service returns an promise
4. api service makes HTTP request (`api.service.ts`)
5. api service resolves promise
6. redux action receives promise & dispatches action to store
7. React component receives promise & disables its own loading state

Everything is working fine, but I get the following typescript error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/actions/workbench-groups.actions.ts:8:3
TS2322: Type '(dispatch: any) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<any>'.
Property '[Symbol.toStringTag]' is missing in type '(dispatch: any) => Promise<any>'.
```

Here are the relevant parts of the three components:

**workbench-group.view.tsx**

```
  componentDidMount() {
this.setState({isFetchingWbGroups: true});
this.props.wbGroupActions.fetchWbGroups()
  .then(() => {
    this.setState({isFetchingWbGroups: false});
  });
```

}

**workbench-group.actions.ts**

```
const fetchWbGroupsAction = createAction(WorkbenchUserActions.WORKBENCH_GROUPS_FETCHED, workbenchGroups => workbenchGroups);
export const fetchWbGroups = ():Promise<TResponseData> => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return fetchWithAuth(ApiRoutesService.wbGroups.routes.fetchWbGroups.path, 'GET', null, dispatch)
      .then((response) => {
        return dispatch(fetchWbGroupsAction(response.data));
      }, (err) => {
        console.log('err', err)
      });
  }
};
```

**api.service.ts**

```
export const fetchWithAuth = (url: string, method: TMethod = 'GET', data: any = null, dispatch):Promise<TResponseData> => {
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": getFromStorage('auth_token')
  };
  return fetchData(url, method, data, dispatch, headers);
};


const fetchData = (url: string, method: TMethod = 'GET', data: any = null, dispatch, headers): Promise<TResponseData> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = {
      body: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null,
      method,
      headers
    };
    // here comes a lot of more stuff...
```

As I said, promises are passed correctly and resolved / rejected in any of the above functions, it is only typescript that complains. What am I doing wrong? I think I have to add a `Dispatch` type to the promise returned in the action, but I don`t find any inside redux-thunk or the redux-thunk typings.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `fetchWbGroups` function is actually returning a function, that is of the shape `(dispatch: any) => Promise<any>` rather than returning `Promise<any>`.

```
return (dispatch) => { // this function takes input of a "dispatch" function
    // and return a Promise
    return fetchWithAuth(ApiRoutesService.wbGroups.routes.fetchWbGroups.path, 'GET', null, dispatch)
      .then((response) => {
        return dispatch(fetchWbGroupsAction(response.data));
      }, (err) => {
        console.log('err', err)
      });
 }
```

Consider just change your type declaration?